# Making a Discord Verification System

Tags: mysql, node.js

So I am trying to make a discord bot with 2 commands:

!addver {verification code} & !verify {code}

the codes will be stored in a MySQL database hosted on my computer using XAMPP. I have successfully gotten it to add the verification code to the database, but right now I am having trouble trying to get it to read the table, and do what I am telling it to.

This is the verify command that I have at the moment:

```html
if (isCommand("verify",message)) {
  if (err) throw err;
  con.query("SELECT Code FROM verf", function (err, result, fields) {
   if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result[1].code);
  });
 }
```

And this is my database. Ignore Name, thats just for my own record of who makes a verification code:
https://gyazo.com/324b4537a975268e8c5ea38edd08767b

EDIT:

Got the code working to find the code that people enter, but cant get it to do anything afterwards. The final if is where the issue is at the moment

```
if (isCommand("verify",message)) {
    var fsql = "SELECT * FROM `verf` WHERE `Code` LIKE ?";
    var vals = [
        [args[0]]
    ];
con.query(fsql, [vals], function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);

    if (result.RowDataPacket.Code === (args[0])) return message.channel.send("You have entered an invalid code!")
        message.member.addRole(WHITELISTED);
})}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: At the moment, its not doing anything. It doesnt seem to be able to read the table, or the person's text when they use !verify. The console is just outputting this: https://gyazo.com/89bde30327f56861c0184af6fd3e45a4

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at https://github.com/human-internet/discord-bot  for some guidance, to use, or to contribute. humanID is a open source verification bot on discord that has worked really well for me. Built with Python and Django, it is easy to use and the company is a non-profit supported by Harvard and Mozilla!